# Postgres select only if table exists

Tags: python, postgresql, select, exists

How can I execute

```
select * from my_table
```

but avoid throwing errors if my_table doesn't exist

Is it possible?

UPDATE: I'm woking in Odoo, I create the table when user presses a button, so for the very first time when my module is installed the table won't exist and I don't want to see the error.

I solved it in python by using:

```
try: cr.execute(my_query)
expetion: pass
```

I'm sorry if I wasn't explicit enough, this is my first question here :P

Comment: By checking the database metadata / schema information tables - that depends on where Postgre stores them (i.e. MySQL has specific tables that hold such information, in Oracle they can be queried from views). You need to check the DBMS docs.

Comment: How is it even possible that you're querying from a table that does not exist?

Comment: Strange situation, but you can check it before: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/infoschema-tables.html

Comment: You could wrap that into a function and catch the error inside PL/pgSQL, but then you need to do `select * from my_table_function()`

Comment: What should the query return if there is no table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you run it in some kind of a function? If not, this whole question makes no sense... If yes - simply try to catch the error, as described here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

You would need to trap `42P01   undefined_table` SQLSTATE.

So in your function you could do:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM sometable
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN undefined_table THEN
    -- Do something
  WHEN others THEN
    -- Do something else
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sending the query from a function in Python. Thanxs to you I found out Python has a try-expetion function to avoid expected errors

Comment: It seems like a totally diffrent case :) I meant trapping errors inside a PL/pgSQL function (procedure ran on the server-side). You write about catching the error on a client-side. Anyway - glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

As an addtional note (not related to Postgresql), when you start the Odoo server, you should ensure that the -u flag is set to ensure that your odoo customization is applied by the Odoo ORM. This ensure that any modifications you have made such as table creation/modification is applied to your Postgresql DB.

So, from the CLI:

`openerp-server -u module_name`

or

`openerp-server -u all`

to update all modules